# Multiple Data frame being produced and other problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

Borrowing a solution from @DGS, to slice rows using user input based on YYMM in the Data frame, I noticed a few problems, when using this code,

```
import pandas as pd

# Inputs
start_time = input('Start Period: ') # 1900 Jan or 1900
end_time = input('End Period: ') # 1910 May or 1910

# If month is present
if len(start_time.split()) > 1:
    start_year, start_month = start_time.split()
# no start month
else:
    start_year = start_time
    start_month = 'Jan'
# If end month
if len(end_time.split()) > 1:
    end_year, end_month = end_time.split()

#no end month
else:
    end_year = end_time
    end_month = 'Dec'

months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year', 'Month']) # output dataframe

# Iterate between start and end year
for i in range(int(start_year), int(end_year)+1):
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame() #temporary dataframe
    if i == int(start_year):
        month_list = months[months.index(start_month):]
    elif i == int(end_year):
        month_list = months[:months.index(end_month)+1] if end_month != 'Dec' else months[:months.index(end_month)+1]
    else:
        month_list = months

    temp_df['Month'] = month_list
    temp_df['Year'] = i

    print(temp_df)
```

Firstly, when printing user input from different years will cause multiple Data frame to be produce,
(just want it to be one single Data frame)

```
Start Period: 1990
End Period: 1992
   Month  Year
0    Jan  1990
1    Feb  1990
2    Mar  1990
3    Apr  1990
4    May  1990
5    Jun  1990
6    Jul  1990
7    Aug  1990
8    Sep  1990
9    Oct  1990
10   Nov  1990
11   Dec  1990
   Month  Year
0    Jan  1991
1    Feb  1991
2    Mar  1991
3    Apr  1991
4    May  1991
5    Jun  1991
6    Jul  1991
7    Aug  1991
8    Sep  1991
9    Oct  1991
10   Nov  1991
11   Dec  1991
   Month  Year
0    Jan  1992
1    Feb  1992
2    Mar  1992
3    Apr  1992
4    May  1992
5    Jun  1992
6    Jul  1992
7    Aug  1992
8    Sep  1992
9    Oct  1992
10   Nov  1992
11   Dec  1992
```

Secondly but not the least, when printing user input from the same year will cause the Data Frame to always end at Dec, (just want it to end at the end time)

```
Start Period: 1990 Feb
End Period: 1990 Mar
   Month  Year
0    Feb  1990
1    Mar  1990
2    Apr  1990
3    May  1990
4    Jun  1990
5    Jul  1990
6    Aug  1990
7    Sep  1990
8    Oct  1990
9    Nov  1990
10   Dec  1990
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your looping only serves for `end_year > start_year`, therefore for the minimum code change here is giving the conditional when `end_year == start_year`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year', 'Month']) # output dataframe

# Iterate between start and end year
if (start_year < end_year):
    for i in range(int(start_year), int(end_year) + 1):
        if i == int(start_year):
            month_list = months[months.index(start_month):]
        elif i == int(end_year):
            month_list = months[:months.index(end_month)+1]
        else:
            month_list = months

        df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
        df_temp['Month'] = month_list
        df_temp['Year'] = i

        df = df.append(df_temp, ignore_index=True)
elif (start_year == end_year):
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
        df_temp['Month'] = months[months.index(start_month):months.index(end_month)+1]
        df_temp['Year'] = start_year

        df = df.append(df_temp, ignore_index=True)
        
print(df)
```

Result:

```
start_time = '1910 Mar'
end_time = '1910 Jun'
```

[image]

Comment: One last problem, when I try to print an output based on different years like `start_time = '1910'` and `end_time = '1911'` it duplicates the dataframe based on the number of years, thus for this example it gives one dataframe 1910 and one more to 1911, how can I merge both of them together and any other time correlation?

Comment: @JohnNg Just leverage the `df` as global variable then append it through local `df_temp`. I have updated post

Comment: @JohnNg any stucks coming? If it solved your problem, please mark it as accepted answer. Thank you.